# How to write a raw SQL query in Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, postgresql

I want to use following SQL query in Django but I was unable to use that after trying directly with raw SQL. The SQL works directly while executing on PostgreSQL query window but on Django did not work.

The SQL is to find immediate lower value before a number 22522. I would like to use that in QuerySet format or in raw SQL. Added SQL query below-

```
SELECT id, name, zip 
FROM region 
WHERE zip >= (SELECT max(zip) FROM region WHERE zip < 22522) 
AND zip <= (SELECT min(zip) FROM region WHERE zip>22522) 
ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 1
```

Here is the code which I tried to use in raw query format. I saw, any other simple SQL query inside the `c.execute()` print result data correctly.

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as c:
    c.execute("SELECT id, name, zip FROM region WHERE zip>=(SELECT max(zip) 
    FROM region WHERE zip<22522) AND zip<=(SELECT min(zip) FROM region 
    WHERE zip>22522) ORDER BY zip ASC LIMIT 1")

    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row[1])
```

Comment: what is the error (complete traceback please)

Comment: there's no reason why you shouldn't use a raw query. But instead of using a cursor, do MyModel.objects.raw(..) that still gives you the full power for Django.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the result back in QuerySet format you need to start with a Djano model, for example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    birth_date = models.DateField(...)

>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
        print(p)
```

For more detail, visit the Django documentation at: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/)